# How to add data and return result

Tags: c#

I am getting null at the result and I think its because I am not adding data to the actual output but if I do then I get exception

If I add data like this
`result.Result.Items = new List<Item>();` object reference
`result.Result.Items.Add(textField);` I get null reference

```
public class Result <T, TError>
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
}

 public class Doc 
    {
        public Items Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Here I am adding data

```
  public Result<Doc, Error> ReturnDataSample()
            {
                var result = new Result<Doc, Error>();
                var doc = new Doc();
                doc.Items = new List<Item>();
    
                doc.Source.ItemsRawData = "Json";
                var imageField = new ImageField();
                imageField.Image = new Image();
                imageField.Image.Data = "image";
                imageField.PageIndex = 1;
                
                doc.Items.Add(imageField);
           
    
    
                TextField textFormField = new TextFormField();
                textField.Text = "originalValue ";
                textField.PageIndex = 1;
                textFField.FieldType = "Test";
    
              doc.Items.Add(textField);
    
    
              return result;
```

here I am Getting result

```
 var data =  regula.ReturnDataSample();
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.WriteLine(data.Result);
```

If I add data like this
`result.Result.Items = new List<Item>();` object reference
`result.Result.Items.Add(textField);` I get null reference

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. It is unclear what the actual question or problem is. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you are trying to do and what the current error/exception message is, maybe even add a [mcve] to show the problem.

Comment: You are not setting the `Result.Result` property anywhere.

Comment: thank you for kind answer, I have tried but If I add data like this result.Result.Items = new List<Item>(); object reference result.Result.Items.Add(textField); I get null reference

Comment: I am not sure how to add the data to the result

Comment: `result.Result = doc;`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that `Result` is never initialized, as Progman has already pointed that out in the comment section. You cannot add an item to that which does not exist:

```
result.Result = doc;
result.Result.Items.Add(textField);
```